# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Jupyter Notebook to begin typing in newly created cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, shortcut

I assumed that there would be a keyboard shortcut to begin typing within a newly created Jupyter Notebook cell, but I titled my question asking **if** it even exists to not build any assumptions. If it does exist, please also include in your answer the shortcut to use.

I will try to provide as much relevant information as possible that will help in answering my question:
I installed Jupyter Notebook on my Windows 10 PC from their website (not using Anaconda). I view and edit Jupyter Notebook files in my Google Chrome browser. After running a cell with Ctrl+Enter, I press b to create a new cell below. I would like to immediately begin typing within that cell without having to click inside that cell with a mouse.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a builtin-shortcut that does exactly what you want. Just enter a cell an press `Alt + Enter`. This will execute the current selected cell, insert a new cell below it and enter edit mode.

Notice, that this also works if you are not in edit mode.

[image]

My setup is a little bit different than yours. Here is a reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press just Enter it will start editing mode in the currently selected cell. So if you do the Alt + Enter to run a cell and create a new cell below, just press Enter again and you will be able to start typing in the cell.

Edit: I also just discovered that if you press 'h' when you have a cell selected but not in edit mode, it brings up a window with all the keyboard shortcuts.